NFTs made from other NFTs
I am working my first ethereum dapp, a supply chain app which tracks the movement of meat products from farm to fork. I have decided to digitise these as ERC721 NFTs, starting with the animal at the farm. The issue I am having is regarding how I can represent the processing of an animal into a product. Let's say I have an animal with id 1. It is slaughtered and the carcass is then cut up into pieces. My though process is that each of these pieces needs to be distinct with it's own id, even though you can have more than one of the same piece e.g. a chicken has 2 wings. These pieces are then used to make a product e.g. a pack of wings from various animals. By having each animal, part, product have it's own unique id, it allows for the end consumer to know where the product came from in terms of what part it came from and what animal it came from.
I looked into ERC-6059 standard which would allow me to have the animal as the parent NFT, which would then have children NFTs (parts) which in turn would have children (products). However, I am not sure how it would work in terms of ownership since they're all owned by the owner of the parent.
Within the supply chain, once an animal is slaughtered and cut, that NFT's journey stops. And now the next NFT is tracked. So if the owner of the animal is let's say the processor. Once it's cut into parts, the ownership of the animal would have to be transferred every time the part/product changes hands which doesn't really make any sense.
Does it make sense to have multiple contracts for each type of NFT i.e. a contract managing an animal from the farm to where it is cut, a contract for processing the part into a product and a contract managing the product to the consumer?
I'm interested to get you guys' ideas on whether I am approaching this in a way that makes sense, or whether I am over complicating things.
Appreciate it.
